# I want to validate two columns from my database "name and group" if it exists display already exists and if it doesn't exist insert into the database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

this the html with ajax and it displays successful and inserts into the database but how can I display error message if the name is already exist after the validation

```
<form action="" id="manage-project">
```

```
                <label for="" class="control-label">Project Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="name"  value="<?php echo isset($name) ? $name : '' ?>">
            </div><div class="form-group">
      <label for="" class="control-label">Project Group </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="pname" required value="<?php echo isset($pname) ? $pname : '' ?>">

    </div>
<div class="card-footer border-top border-info">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <button class="btn btn-flat  bg-gradient-primary mx-2" form="manage-project">Save</button>
            <button class="btn btn-flat bg-gradient-secondary mx-2" type="button" onclick="location.href='index.php?page=project_list'">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
$('#manage-project').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    start_load()
    $.ajax({
        url:'ajax.php?action=save_project',
        data: new FormData($(this)[0]),   

        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        method: 'POST',
        type: 'POST',
        success:function(resp){
            if(resp == 1){
                alert_toast('Data successfully saved',"success");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    location.href = 'index.php?page=project_list'
                },2000)
            }
        }
    })
```

This is the  insertion query and I guess I need select query to validate the name. help me out here

```
function save_project(){
    extract($_POST);
    $data = "";
    foreach($_POST as $k => $v){
        if(!in_array($k, array('id','user_ids')) && !is_numeric($k)){
            if($k == 'description')
                $v = htmlentities(str_replace("'","&#x2019;",$v));
            if(empty($data)){
                $data .= " $k='$v' ";
            }else{
                $data .= ", $k='$v' ";
            }
        }
    }
    if(isset($user_ids)){
        $data .= ", user_ids='".implode(',',$user_ids)."' ";
    }
    if(empty($id)){
        $save = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO project_list set $data");
    }else{
        $save = $this->db->query("UPDATE project_list set $data where id = $id");
    }
    if($save){
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$check = $this->db->query("select name from project_list where and pname='$pname' or name='$name'")->num_rows;
    if($check > 0){
        return 2;
        exit;
    }
```